# High amount of API calls from Smart Map

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I have a Smart Map setup and [installed it on a site](https://missionthriftstore.com/store/find).

The section averages 300 page views per day according to Google Analytics, but Google API is maxing out the 2500 requests on the free plan. I've bumped up to a paid plan, but does anyone know why there are so many requests?

Comment: Is this for Craft 2 or Craft 3? Which version of Smart Map are you running?

Comment: I'm on Craft 2, Smart Map 2.4.0. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like @SamC nailed it. I’ve also seen some recent indications that Google has adjusted how they are counting API calls, so that may be relevant as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing the map is multiple API calls. And interacting with the map uses additional API calls.

I opened the Inspector (in Firefox here), and you can see a ton of calls to maps.google.com - see all the file calls `vt?pb...` - each one is a block of the map background.

[image]

And then, as you drag the map around, zoom, etc, it's making additional calls to get the portions of the map it doesn't have. And you can see them pop-up in the inspector.

So, a bunch of calls to draw the map, and more as you change your view of the map.

You could try the static image map `{{ craft.smartMap.img(locations, options) }}` instead of the standard `{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}`

Alternative ideas, disable 'zoomable' and/or 'scrollable' in your map settings ([more about those options here](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/customizing-the-map-in-twig/)) - less interaction = less api calls.

The static map loads a lot less API resources, but takes a longer to generate (and just isn't as good).